# scrollLeft scrolls to a not round px value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i use scrollLeft to scroll to the right 50px

but then i log the value of scrollLeft, it is 49.599998474121094px not 50px

how to make it scroll 50px

[here is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Teqw.png)

thanks for your support

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
        elmnt.scrollTop += 10;
        document.getElementById ("demo").innerHTML = "Horizontally: " + elmnt.scrollLeft + "px<br>Vertically: " + elmnt.scrollTop + "px";
    }
```

```css
#myDIV {
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #content {
            height: 800px;
            width: 2000px;
            background-color: coral;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to scroll the contents of div by 50px horizontally and 10px vertically.</p>

    <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Click the button many times to scroll the same amount each time.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll contents of div</button><br><br>

    <div id="myDIV">
        <div id="content">
            Some text inside a div element.<br><br>
            Some text inside a div element.
        </div>
    </div>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It shows `50px` for me.

Comment: @Spectric how :v

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Spectric chrome

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpo9O.png) is what it shows for me.

Comment: @Spectric omg it still shows me 49.599998474121094px :v

Comment: Shows 50 for me too. Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 Win10

Answer (score 0):

Your Chrome **browser window** is most probably set to a **zoom of 125%** - which leads to this awkward result:

`49.599998474121094px`

Set the Zoom to **100%** and there it is:

`50px`